# Output in nested loops

Tags: java, loops, nested, bluej

I'm trying to get this output:

```
123454321
1234 4321
123   321
12     21
1       1
```

I have tried doing this first:

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Then,putting a '\t' and putting this next to the above:

```
4321
4321
321
21
1
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having exactly? Please also post the code you have used to get your current result. Lastly, please add the language you are using to the tags of the question. This will attract the attention of the relevant people.

Comment: Any language in specific?

Comment: I have been using Java(compiler BlueJ) I fail to get the output correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code gives the output you mentioned

```
package com.hello;

public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printNumbers(5,5);
}

private static void printNumbers(int max,int iteration)
{
    String line ="";
    int NoOfSpaces = (max-iteration)*2 -1;

    if(iteration == 0)
        return;
    for(int i=1;i<=iteration;i++)
        line = line+i;
    for(int i =0;i<NoOfSpaces;i++)
        line = line+" ";
    if(max != iteration)
        line = line +iteration;
    for(int i=iteration-1;i>=1;i--)
        line = line +i;
    System.out.println(line);
    printNumbers(max,--iteration);

  }
}
```

let me know if you have any further questions....

Comment: Can this be done without using the package? If so,how?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved recursively using the following code:

```
public static void recurseForward(int to, int space) {
    if (to == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    recurseBackward(to, space);
}

public static void recurseBackward(int from, int space) {
    for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int i = from; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    recurseForward(from - 1, space + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    recurseForward(5, 0);
}
```